# Обработка 502(BadGateway) в TelegramBot C#

Tags: c#, telegram-bot

Подскажите, как добавить/исправить существующий обработчик bad gateway, сейчас код выглядит вот так:

```
var updates = await Bot.GetUpdatesAsync(offset); // получаем обновления

foreach (var update in updates) // Перебираем все обновления
{
  try
     {
      var message = update.Message;
      if (message.Type == Telegram.Bot.Types.Enums.MessageType.Text)
          {
            //Обработка команд
            offset = update.Id + 1;
             Console.WriteLine(update.Type);
           }
     }
  catch (Telegram.Bot.Exceptions.BadRequestException)
     {
       BadGateway++;
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1);
      }
}
```

Запросы идут через long polling. Заранее благодарен!

Comment: что именно нужно исправить? в чём вообще проблема?

Comment: @Anatol обработчик ошибки не срабатывает. Все равно крашится раз в 10-12 часов

Comment: Так выполнение и не доходит до обработчика. Получение обновлений нужно заворачивать, а не их обработку

Comment: @Anatol Большое спасибо!

Comment: @Anatol Да, точно. Я просто недавно на стаке, извиняйте

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот так попробуйте:

```
    try
    {
        var updates = await Bot.GetUpdatesAsync(offset); // получаем обновления
        foreach (var update in updates) // Перебираем все обновления
        {
            var message = update.Message;
            if (message.Type == Telegram.Bot.Types.Enums.MessageType.Text)
            {
                //Обработка команд
                offset = update.Id + 1;
                Console.WriteLine(update.Type);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Telegram.Bot.Exceptions.BadRequestException ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        BadGateway++;
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
```